# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Throws an Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm trying to convert current date to a specified format.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I'm receiving the following exception.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My local TimeZone is (UTC+10:00)Melbourne.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to change DateTime.Now.ToString() to DateTime.Now

Comment: You want to print it in a specific format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string fm = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
string str = DateTime.Now.ToString(fm, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, fm, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT:**

A better way to achieve the date in the format would be like

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU"); //Melbourne
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/IUJfiI)**

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this doesn't accomplish anything - it will just serialize and deserialize the current time. It's equivalent to writing `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Rob question has nothing to indicate that is not what was intended.

Comment: @CoryNelson "I'm trying to convert current date to a specified format." :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code (even if it worked), would do nothing. It would simply serialize and deserialize the date. I believe you're looking for this:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

It doesn't work because `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is giving a string like (I happen to be in the same timezone, and presumably have the same culture as you):

```
14/01/2016 3:54:01 PM
```

Which is of the format:

```
dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
```

Which does not match the format you're using: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`